# Rails link_to disable_with and then remove link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, link-to

I am using Link_to to add some content to my page using ajax, but I only ever want the user doing this once. I am doing this by replacing the link with a new html element in the js.erb file. This is all working fine as follows:

```
<%= link_to(expand_task_subset_user_path(user, li_id: li_id, span_id: span_id, user_tasks_to_expand_sym: user_tasks_to_expand_sym),
    {:method => :get, remote: true, 'data-mahi-link-type'=>'expand_task_subset'}) do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" title="Expand this branch"></i>
<% end %>
```

js.erb file snippet that replaces the link created above:

```
$("#<%=@span_id%> > a:has(i)").replaceWith("<i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign\" title=\"Collapse this branch\"></i>")
```

I noticed today that is was possible to click the link twice before everything in the js.erb file had been completed which meant it inserted the other content twice. I thought the obvious way to remedy this was to add a disable_with like so:

```
<%= link_to(expand_task_subset_user_path(user, li_id: li_id, span_id: span_id, user_tasks_to_expand_sym: user_tasks_to_expand_sym),
    {:method => :get, remote: true, 'data-mahi-link-type'=>'expand_task_subset', data: { disable_with: 'loading...' }}) do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" title="Expand this branch"></i>
<% end %>
```

The problem (I think) is that the disable_with changes the html temporarily and the jquery selector `$("#<%=@span_id%> > a:has(i)")` does not find any matching elements to replace. I have tried disabling the link as the first statement in the js.erb file too, but if you are quick you can still beat it and click twice. Is there another way to disable the link straight after clicking?

**Update:** The disable_with does replace the contents of the 'a' tag so I just changed my jquery selector to be:

```
$("#<%=@span_id%> > a[data-mahi-link-type='expand_task_subset']")
```

instead of looking for the child 'i' tag and now all works great!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use Jquery to disable the link once clicked, something like this :

```
$('#Link').click(function(a) {
    a.preventDefault();
    //other goods
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does't seem to work. I read somewhere that the remote: true stops jquery from unbinding/ die. I might have to look into this further to find a workaround...